# How do you wait for a file to be fully downloaded and then get its path? node js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to download a file, and when it downloads it first has the extension .tmp or .crdownload, and then after it is fully downloaded the extension changes to whatever the correct extension is, for example, .png.

I want to wait until the file no longer has the extension .tmp or .crdownload and then save the new file path to a variable.

How can I do this? I have looked here on Stack Overflow but it is not answering all my questions. This is a unique and specific question. **Just need the resulting code to wait for the file extension to change and save the path to a variable as a string**.

Goal a submitted answer that does the following.

> input file is images.tmp or images.crdownload
>
> Wait for file extension to change
>
> File changes to images.png for example
>
> Save images.png to a variable

Comment: try [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener)

Comment: @Matt Thank You. I looked at it but was not sure how to do it as i am new to node.js. Will you submit an answer?